# get the values from dialog and use them in code behind

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

```
 <div style="display: none" id="CopyNews" title="Enter the newsletter details">
        <div style="position: relative; height: 100%">
            <br />
            <asp:Label ID="MailType" runat="server" Text="type:" />
            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlDlgType" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" />
            <br />
            <br />
            <asp:Label ID="MailTitle" runat="server" Text=" title:" />
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtTitle" runat="server" />
            <br />
            <br />
            <div style="text-align: center;">
                <asp:Button runat="server" ID="YesButton" Text="OK" />
                <asp:Button runat="server" ID="CancelButton" Text="Cancel" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script>
        function OpenNews() {
            $("#CopyNews").dialog({
                width: 'auto',
                height: 'auto',
                modal: true,
                resizable: false,
                position: 'center'
            });
        }
    </script>
```

And after clicking a button ( in code behind ), I display the above dialog:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, this.GetType(), "script", "OpenNews();", true);
```

My intentions:

I do want to use, in codebehind, the DropDownList value and the textBox value after the OK button is clicked and, obviously, when the Cancel button is clicked the dialog should be closed.

How can I achieve these?

Comment: do you want the dropdownlist to issue a regular post or an ajax call ? What does OpenNews() do ? You can set its HTML accordingly to perform a auto post back

Comment: OpenNews() is displaying the dialog

Comment: it displays ddlDlgType ? can you add the html opened by OpenNews() ?

Comment: it displays the div having the id="CopyNews" - the code is in the question

Answer (score -2):

Although that you're using a div in a dialog, the code-behind behavior is maintained. So, you can access properties of that objects normally on code-behind.

You can just handle the `OnClick` ASP.NET event of the `YesButton`(button OK) and check the values of those controls. See code bellow:

```
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="YesButton" Text="OK" OnClick="YesButton_Click" />
```

The only modification is that you have to set `AutoPostBack="false"` in `ddlDlgType`, otherwise your modal will disappear because a postback will happens.

To close when Cancel is clicked, handle the onClick javascript event and try this:

```
$("#CopyNews").dialog( "close" );
```

Comment: he wants the user's selection at the server side, not client.

Comment: Yeah, he can handle the `OnClick` ASP.NET event, not the javascript `onClick` of the button OK.